# sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected docker/php

Tags: php, docker

```
shell_exec("php $filePath 2>&1" . "<" ."$inputPath" );
```

What's wrong with this code?

I tried this code without docker it works but if I use docker it shows error `sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected docker/php`

I am using https://hub.docker.com/_/php

Comment: It's subject to [shell injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)?  When you say "if I use Docker", how exactly are you trying to run it?

Comment: I am trying to make code compiler.

Comment: @DavidMaze Please check code : 

index.php - https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#5p05frlfhjr0k6sgq4ek7zh

Dockerfile - https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#z8izptk5gxvzlu1xhoi8r